# how can i remove submenubar from Menubar in gwt?

Tags: gwt

I am using MenuBar control in gwt (for example **X**) and i am adding a another menubar in main menubar (for example **Y**) with the help of function whose prototype is `addItem(abc, Y)` and now i want to remove this menubar **Y** for this i am using `removeItem(Y)` but this method takes the menuitem argument and here Y is Menubar.so how can i remove menubar from main Menubar.

Thanks 
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new item, `MenuBar` returns the object you just added as a `MenuItem`. Take the following example:

```
MenuBar X = new MenuBar(); // main menu

MenuBar Y = new MenuBar(); // sub menu
Y.addItem("item 1", someCmd);
Y.addItem("item 2", someOtherCmd);
Y.addItem("item 3", someThirdCmd);

MenuItem removableY = X.addItem("Y Menu", Y);
```

You can use the returned `MenuItem` to remove the sub menu `Y` from parent menu `X`, like so:

```
X.removeItem(removableY);
```

For more information, refer to [the `MenuBar` documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html).